# encloud holidays to weekday in Employee reporting "excel 2016"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i build an empty Work schedule Employee reporting

**E6** = the month
**H12** = the yere
**A10-A40** = date with formula `=DATE(H6,E6,1)`
**A11**= `=IF(A10="","",IF(MONTH(A10+1)<>MONTH(A10),"",A10+1))` To limit the days in a month
**B10** = weekday
i have a spreadsheet that called holidays
**A**=holiday date
**B**=name of the holiday
I try to include in the name of the day if it has a holiday the name of the holiday instead of the name of the day
this is my code **B10**

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A10,holidays!A:B,2,0)),TEXT(WEEKDAY(A10),"dddd")
[image]

Comment: Please be more exact in what you want shown as a result. If you want us to help you, add some sample data and sample results.

Comment: in the day column i want to see the name of the holiday instant of the weekday so if the date in A10-A40 mutch one of the holiday date replace the weekday "dddd" to holiday name

Comment: Yes, explain it with sample data, please

Comment: I think you mean using `IFERROR)` instead of `IF(ISERROR())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you have office365 you can use this:

```
=LET(first,D2,
     last,E2,
          hday,A2:A4,
          hdayname,B2:B4,
     seq,first+SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(first,last,"D")+1,,0),
IF(COUNTIF(hday,seq),
   XLOOKUP(seq,hday,hdayname,,0),
   TEXT(seq,"dddd")))
```

[image]

---

Edit after new info shared:

For older Excel versions:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A10,holidays!A:B,2,0)),TEXT(WEEKDAY(A10),"dddd"))` if as written in the post, or:
`IFERROR(INDEX(holidays!B:B,MATCH(A10,holidays!A:A,0)),TEXT(WEEKDAY(A10),"dddd"))` if as shown in the picture.

Comment: no dont have office 365

Comment: But is it in the direction of what you need? (Since you still haven't clarified with sample data / results)

Comment: I created an example with an explanation hoping it will help

Comment: It helps, though the letters on top are confusing. Also your written explanation in the first post says holiday dates and names are the other way around than in the example. Which is correct?

Comment: Please see edit in my answer

Comment: thank you the first code is what i need but i'm gat  "You've entered too few arguments for this function"

Comment: I forgot a bracket (typed the formula in here without testing). Added it in my answer.